# Are there any sure-fire methods for correctly arranging matricies for Gaussian Elimination?

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I am attempting to make a Gaussian Elimination solver for systems of linear equations that contain less than 100 equations. I have roughed out a method for creating and filling in the diagonal of a representing matrix (using row flipping) and the standard solving steps. My method for arranging always produces a filled in diagonal, and my whole program can usually solve small systems of 20*20.

The problem occurs when using the *ith* column of the *ith* row to eliminate the *ith* column of the *jth* row where the *jth* column of the *ith* row proceeds to eliminate the *jth* column of the *jth* row.

The following image will help illustrate the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OARf.png

[image]

Are there any sure-fire ways to arrange a matrix for Gaussian Elimination or alternatively for LU factorization?

Comment: Do you mean pivoting?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel where?

Comment: E.g., [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_element#Partial_and_complete_pivoting).